# httpOnly Cookie Security Flaw

Tags: authentication, cookies, account-security, node.js

I'm bit confused about this security flaw. I'm in real need of help in this :smile:
My express code (not using any sessions, just `cookie-parser`)

```
app.get("/signin", (req, res) => {
    if(!req.query.token) return res.status(403).json({status:403, message:"Authorization Required"});
    let options = {maxAge: 1000 * 604800,httpOnly: true,signed: true,secure: true};
    res.cookie('token', encryptor.encrypt(req.query.token) , options);
    res.status(200).json({status:200, message:"Success"});
});
app.get('/data', (req.res) => {
     let cookie = encryptor.decrypt(req.signedCookies.token);
     db.fetch(cookie).then(data => res.json(data));
})
```

So here, let's say 'A' & 'B' sents sign-in request with a token. The express app should encrypt them and send them in an httpOnly cookie.
Yesterday, 'B' logged in first, pulls his data. After that, 'A' logs in & pulls his data. But right after that, when 'B' again tries to pull his data, he receives 'A's data, which indicates that the request which 'B' sent had the cookie which belongs to 'A'. I don't understand how or why it changed. I thought httpOnly cookies arent domain-wise but user-wise. (Both of the users logged in & pulled the data using a web app in the same domain)

**EDIT:**
After new tests, I was able to find out that, after the very first request, every following request are responded with `304` status code. That means express is sending the cache along with the token. Thats a huge security flaw here since each user data is obtained by his or her token.
Here is another example of what I think is happening:
Users 'A' & 'B'
'A' sents login request first and 'A' receives his encrypted cookie back.
Next, 'B' sends a login request & due to 304, receives 'A's cookie.

Comment: *"I thought httpOnly cookies arent domain-wise but user-wise."* - there is no inherent concept of a user with cookies. Cookies are per domain and per browser profile. If the browser profile is specific to the logged in user depends if the user uses a different device or account on the same device. I don't think that the code you show is sufficient to explain what you see but maybe you are just using the same cookie value for all users? I cannot see any part of your cookie which is specific to the user.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I believe the code is sufficient to demonstrate how the cookies are set. I think I know whats going on, I've added an edit.

Comment: *"That means express is sending the cache along with the token."* - that's not how 304 works. 304 means that the response did not change and that the client (i.e. A or B) should use __their own locally cached copy__ of the response body. No response body is sent by the server with 304. *"I believe the code is sufficient to demonstrate how the cookies are set."* - as I said, I don't think that the code is sufficient to understand the behavior you describe.

Comment: Your edit indicates that you are using some incorrectly configured caching middleware or caching proxy. Perhaps your server can override the default cache algorithm with a response header like `Cache-Control: no-store`, but really the proxy should be configured properly.

Comment: Are A and B using different machines? Or are they both on the same machine on the same browser?

Comment: A and B live on different continents. And yes, it was my api-cache middleware :D